# Cant seem to remove a comma from an object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Story is:
I dont know the keys or the values that are in the object, it's just something that the users input and then i display it. However, when im trying to print it out, it's always a comma there.
For example this is an example of the object: `{ testObject: [ 'this ', 'is ', 'funny ' ]}`

When i print it out it will be: `this ,is ,funny`

My result that i would like should be just `this is funny`

My question is, i need to keep this as an object because when im rendering it only accepts objects so can the object be like:

```
{ testObject: [ 'this ' 'is ' 'funny ' ]}
```

without the commas?

I tried to do something like this, but obviusly didnt work

```
var y = ({testObject});
    for (var o = 0; o < y.length; o++){
      y.replace(/,/, '')[o];
    }
    console.log(y)
```

Would appreciate an example or if there is any solution to do it while still keeping it as an object?

Comment: And how do you "print" it? Array.prototype.join is the new method you should learn about.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array... and it already has spaces - so you can just join the strings:

```js
var x = { testObject: [ 'this ', 'is ', 'funny ' ]};

alert(x.testObject.join(''));
```

If the strings didn't have spaces, you would join with a space: `join(' ')`. You could trim the strings to make things less brittle.

Answer (score 0):

The commas are not part of the data in the array, so you can't remove them by looping over the array and changing each piece of data.

You'll get commas if you implicitly convert the array to a string because it has a default `toString` function that looks something like:

```
return this.join(", ");
```

You'll need to convert it to a string yourself to avoid that. For example:

```
x.textObject.join(" ");
```